# Looking for a test that produces data similar to Eye-Tracking tests

Tags: computational-linguistics, applied-linguistics

I was conducting a study about Shell Nouns and how they affect the brain. The issue was that corona came up and the university is still shut down and everything is only online.
For my study I worked in our Eye-Tracking lab. I had my data prepared and everything set up to do the study but because of the Covid regulations I am not allowed to enter the lab anymore.

I need to get my data somehow online because I cannot work directly with people at the moment.

So I was thinking about some kind of program that only shows like 2-3 words in a small window and you navigate through the text via keyboard input. It should also save the input cause this will show me later on where exactly the person was looking at and how often he/she needed to go back or forth to understand the sentence.
I know that there is a similar test used to figure out reading speed and I thought that maybe something like this already exists. Otherwise I would try to program something like this myself but honestly I am not that good with this.

I am really happy about any input even if you can just tell me names of tests that might be interesting for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with the self-paced reading paradigm

Comment: Actually this helped me a lot. Thanks. This was btw also the test I had in my mind but I forgot the name of it.
I am creating my own test based on this now and currently have a programmer write the code for me.

Thanks man